# How do I delete a Conan package version uploaded to Artifactory (on the free tier)

Tags: artifactory

I have set up a free Artifactory account (and thus don't get the fancy tree based repository browser, or at least can't find how to access it). While experimenting I have uploaded some variations of a package, and would now like to remove some of them.

[image: Screenshot of package view]

In the above package, I'd love to delete versions "4.4" and "4.3+pi", leaving only "4.3+rpi". How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, to get the tree navigation browser, click on "artifacts" under "Artifactory" and goto the repository in which the packages were deployed and delete the needed packages by right-clicking or clicking on the actions.
[image]

update:
screenshot for tree browser
[image]

Comment: How do I "get to the tree navigation browser"? I'm not sure that's available in the free tier

Comment: It is available, if you see in the screenshot there is an artifacts button under the Artifactory, click on that button, it will redirect to the tree browser and you can delete it. See the updated answer for the screenshot.